# django-restframework detailview issue

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Using [django-rest-framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) I trying to implement few simple APIs.

Following is the code.

Issues I am facing is:

1. The **products/(?P\d+)/** never executes the ProductsDetailView. I always get all the list of products irrespective usage of IDs in the URLs.
2. But, when I remove the **products/** from URLs, then I get the single product as response. But, unfortunately now I cannot have all the products, as the URL for that API is removed.

I am not sure what wrong I am doing because of which this issue is happenning. Please help me.

**MODEL:**

```
class Product(models.Model):
product_owner = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name='User')
product_imported_via = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="0", null=False, choices=PRODUCT_IMPORT_SOURCE,
                                        verbose_name='Source of import')
product_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, verbose_name='Product title')
product_description = models.TextField(max_length=250, verbose_name='Product description')
product_qty = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Quantity')
product_mrp = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, verbose_name='Maximum retail price')
product_offer_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, verbose_name='Selling price')
_product_discount_amount = models.FloatField(null=True, editable=False, verbose_name='Discount amount',
                                             db_column='product_discount_amount')
_product_discount_percentage = models.IntegerField(null=True, editable=False, verbose_name='Disount percentage',
                                                   db_column='product_discount_percentage')
product_sku = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, unique=True, verbose_name='SKU',help_text='Enter Product Stock Keeping Unit')
product_barcode = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, verbose_name='Barcode')
archive = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

**SERIALIZER:**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Product

class ProductsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = Product
    fields = ('id','product_title', 'product_description', 'product_qty', 'product_mrp',
              'product_offer_price','product_discount_amount','product_discount_percentage',
              'product_sku','product_barcode')
```

**VIEWS:**

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .models import Product
from .serializers import ProductsSerializer
from django.http import Http404

#Create your views here.
class ProductsListView(APIView):

def get(self, request):

    print('In update list')
    updates = Product.objects.all()
    serializer = ProductsSerializer(updates, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)


class ProductsDetailView(APIView):

def get_object(self, pk):
    try:
        return Product.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except Product.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404

def get(self, request, pk):
    update = self.get_object(pk)
    serializer = ProductsSerializer(update)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

**URLS:**

```
from products.views import ProductsListView, ProductsDetailView
urlpatterns = [
              url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
              url(r'^products/', ProductsListView.as_view()),
              url(r'^products/(?P<pk>\d+)/', ProductsDetailView.as_view()),
          ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason you aren't using '$' to signify the end of a string in the routing?

Aside from that, if what you are intending to do is to have a list view and then an individual view for each product with an ID, you should revisit the Django Routers documentation as you won't need two routing statements to achieve this.

Comment: Yes. Adding '$' at the end of the string worked. I missed to add those.